# How to make a calendar tab for every user showing user's events?

Tags: 6, users, organic-groups, datetime

I followed the tutorial [Calendars for Organic Groups - A simple tutorial for D6](https://www.drupal.org/node/679808), and successfully created a calendar for every group in my site showing its events. I also managed to show the calendar as a tab in every group homepage using the path `node/%/calendar`.

Now I want to create a second calendar page, shown as a tab in every user profile page, which will provide the user information about all the events that are registered in the groups the user is a member of. I created a second view, and configured it to show all the events of the site.

How can I limit this view to only show the events from all the groups? How can I add its page as a tab in every user profile? Is there a way to limit the access to this tab to only the user that owns the profile?

Comment: I follow this tutorial for similar functionality: [Organic groups calendars and dates integration](http://mohitaghera.drupalgardens.com/content/organic-group-calendars-and-dates-integration-drupal-7) Is for Drupal 7 and it shows how you can create a tab.

Comment: http://tylerfrankenstein.com/code/drupal-create-menu-tab-views-node-content-type read it

Answer (score 1):

Clone the default view "OG all user group content" provided by Organic Groups. Filter content type based on events and thats it. This displays all the events from all the groups the user is subscribed to.

You can also change the display style to calendar and add a bunch of other settings.